# How to authenticate with third party system using RestAssured

Tags: web-services, rest-assured

I'm trying to hit a web service using RestAssured. I'm struggling with authentication which is actually performed by a third party system. Details are given below:

1. My web service requires session ID & Cookie in the request header. Otherwise the service call will be failed.
2. For that I need to fetch Session Id & Cookie after the authentication.
3. Authentication is done by third party service and it takes the windows credentials for authentication.
4. When I launch my app URL on browser, say: 'XYZ.com/dim' it will be redirected to authentication service using a URL like:

> http://hantweb.DOMAIN.com/authenticate/encdefault.asp?location=XYZ.com/dim

5. After the authentication it will again be redirected to actual application back.

I tried below code but it says: "**401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.**" even though my credentials are correct.

```
RestAssured.given().auth().basic("userID", "password").get("http://hantweb.DOMAIN.com/authenticate/encdefault.asp?location=XYZ.com/dim")
```

I'm confused no idea what I've missed here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some trial and error and finally understood that I need to use `.auth().ntlm(userId, password,"","")` as the authentication. Here I'm using windows credentials as basic or any other auth type won't work in this case.
This answer can help someone in need.